# Is there a way to find patterns in a column in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mathematical-optimization, missing-data

I have `Pandas DataFrame` of `missing dataframes` from a larger `dataset`. The column `web_id` contains the `ids` that were missing from the `larger dataframe`.

I am trying to find a pattern in the way they were missing from the larger `dataset`.

For example, the following code is reproducible on your local computer. The below is a sample of my dataset at the moment:

```
pd.DataFrame({
"web_id": [43291, 43300, 43313, 43316, 43335, 43345, 43346, 43353, 43361, 43373, 43383, 43387, 43416],
"date": "12/17/2019"
})
```

I believe there is some sort of patterns in the missingness. How can I find the sequence of the `web_id` to further understand how the data were missing from the larger `dataset`?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: *"I believe there is some sort of patterns in the missingness."* What makes you think so? This is not a question on a specific programming problem, at best it's some sort of puzzle.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not concerned with a specific programming problem.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> x = pd.DataFrame({ "web_id": [43291, 43300, 43313, 43316, 43335,
> 43345, 43346, 43353, 43361, 43373, 43383, 43387, 43416], })
>
> ls = [] 
> for i in x.values:  
>    for j in i:        
>        ls.append(j)
>
> for i in range(len(ls)-1):    
>     print(ls[i+1] - ls[i])
> ```

This will print out the difference between each value in the columns. I did not notice any mathematical sequence, at least using this difference method.

output: 9,
13,
3,
19,
10,
1,
7,
8,
12,
10,
4,
29

Actually, you can go here https://oeis.org/ to verify if the sequence has been found before. It doesn't seem so. Good luck!

Comment: This is not working. Can you check your 3rd line of code. There is an indent error

Comment: Super! danke. nice reference

Comment: Indentation fixed :)

Comment: when I tried it with my dataset. I get the error: TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable